# Simple async eachLimit example throws range error?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, express, npm, async.js

My code is very simple:

```
async.eachLimit(lines, 5, function iterator(line, complete) {
    console.log(line)
    complete(null);
}, function done(err) {
  if(err) throw err;
    console.log('done yo!');
});
```

However, I keep getting the following error. What am I not understanding?

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Comment: I tried 'var lines;' or 'var lines = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six'];' and the code above, it worked fine. are you sure it's not something else that's causing the error?

Comment: The iterator needs to be `asynchronous`. Your function looks synchronous: this means that the for each execution the stack is growing and growing until it reaches the limit and throws an error. Everytime you call `setTimeout` or any other `async` friend the call stack is cleared and there's new room for more functions. Try to change your iterator function to the following: `function iterator(line, complete){ setTimeout(complete); }`